# 「ユーザへフィードバックを共有する」モーダルダイアログのマジックリンクが動作していない

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

### 不具合事象

メインサイトのレビュー画面で使用されているマジックリンクがリンク化されていない場合があります。問題が再現した際のスクリーンショットを以下に示します。

これは新しいユーザの回答をレビューする場面において、フィードバックを共有しようとしたときの画像です。この画像から、表示されているモーダルダイアログの「回答内容がはっきりしません」と「回答に裏付け情報が必要です」の説明文に含まれる、編集画面へのマジックリンク `[edit]` がプレーンテキストとして表示されていることが確認できます。当該文字列の ja.traducir.win 上の URL は次の2つです：

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15455
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15456

この文字列以外にマジックリンクが使用されている箇所はないか、[こちらのStack Exchangeのマジックリンク一覧](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306)を参考に調べましたが、見つけることができなかったため、問題が生じているのはこの2つの文字列のみだと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 再現環境

- OS：Windows 10 64-bit
- ブラウザ：Opera One(バージョン: 104.0.4944.36)

Comment: とりあえず Traducir で `[edit]` の両端に半角スペースを入れてみました。これで認識されるかもしれません。

Comment: もしかしたらこれは意図通りの挙動かもしれなくて、フィードバック表示画面ではリンクとして展開されないもののコメントになるとリンクになるタイプのやつかもしれないな〜と思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 短い答え:

少なくとも該当のモーダルダイアログでは (ハイパーリンクにならず) `[edit]` のまま表示されるのが正常な動作と考えられます。

#### もう少し詳しく:

- もともとマジックリンク (日本語版ヘルプでは "短縮リンク" と訳してます) は **コメント欄でのみ** 記述できる特殊な記法です。
- モーダルダイアログで選択した文言がテンプレートとしてそのままコメント欄に投稿されます。

コメントとして投稿された結果でハイパーリンクになっていればよくて、逆に言えばモーダルウィンドウでリンクになっているとコメント投稿時にはただのテキストになってしまいます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。最終的にコメント欄でリンクになっていれば良いとのこと、たしかにおっしゃるとおりですね。ひとまず nekketsuuu さんが適用してくださった変更で変化があるか、様子を見てみます。

Comment: マジックリンクの両端へスペースを追加した状態でも変化が見られないことから、仕様上正しい動作ということで、本質問を解決済みにします。